# Counting the number of specific occurrences in a java String

Tags: java, string, count, charat

I am attempting to solve a problem where I create a method that counts the number of occurrences of capital and lowercase ("A" or "a") in a certain string. I have been working on this problem for a week now, and the main error that I am receiving is that "char cannot be dereferenced". Can anyone point me in the correct direction on this Java problem? Thank you.

```
class Main{ 
    public static int countA (String s)
    {
        String s1 = "a";
        String s2 = "A";
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
            String s3 = s.charAt(i); 
            if (s3.equals(s1) || s3.equals(s2)){
                count += 1;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("");
            }
        }
    }

   //test case below (dont change):
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(countA("aaA")); //3
        System.out.println(countA("aaBBdf8k3AAadnklA")); //6
    }
}
```

Comment: first mistake `s.length` , second mistake `String s3 = s.charAt(i);`

Comment: What do you mean "first mistake". What should I change it to? @OusmaneMahyDiaw

Comment: for the first change to `s.length()` for the second change to `String s3 = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));` . another good solution is suggested by @ScaryWombat below within the anwer section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try a simpler solution

```
String in = "aaBBdf8k3AAadnklA";
String out = in.replace ("A", "").replace ("a", "");
int lenDiff = in.length () - out.length ();
```

Also as @chris mentions in his answer, the String could be converted to lowercase first and then only do a single check

Comment: Very intuitive solution here!

Answer (score 4):

For counting the number of time `'a'` or `'A'` appears in a String:

```
public int numberOfA(String s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) == 'a')
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Or just replace everything else and see how long your string is:

```
int numberOfA = string.replaceAll("[^aA]", "").length();
```

Answer (score 4):

> the main error that I am receiving is that "char cannot be
>   dereferenced"

change this:

```
s.length  // this syntax is incorrect
```

to this:

```
s.length()  // this is how you invoke the length method on a string
```

also, change this:

```
String s3 = s.charAt(i);   // you cannot assign a char type to string type
```

to this:

```
String s3 = Character.toString(s.charAt(i));  // convert the char to string
```

---

another solution to accomplishing your task in a simpler manner is by using the [`Stream#filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method. Then convert each `String` within the `Stream` to lowercase prior to comparison, if any Strings match `"a"` we keep it, if not we ignore it and at the end, we simply return the count.

```
public static int countA(String input)
{
    return (int)Arrays.stream(input.split("")).filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().equals("a")).count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of times character **a** and **A** appear in **string**.

```
int numA = string.replaceAll("[^aA]","").length();
```